# Converting nonlinear matrix inequality to an LMI

Tags: matrices, control-theory, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

I am fairly new to semidefinite programming (SDP). I have the following semidefinite program in matrix $X$ and vector $p$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|Np\|^2\\ \text{subject to} & M(X,p) \prec 0\\ & X = X^{T} \succ 0\end{array}$$

with

$$M(X,p) := cX + ((A-Bp^{T}N^{T})X)+((A-Bp^{T}N^{T})X)^{T}$$

where $c > 0$ is a scalar. I know that the simplest and straightforward way to solve this problem is recasting $M(X,k)$ with a proper change of variable that leads to an LMI (see [this book](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/lmibook/lmibook.pdf), in particular by imposing $Bp^{T}N^{T}X=t$ with $t$ a new variable).

In this way I obtain:

Unfortunately in my particular case I can't do that and I would like to recast this matrix inequality which is non-linear into a linear matrix inequality but solving it with respect to $p$ and $X$. Is there a possible way to do that?

Or anyway if the question above have no answers, any different approach to the change of variables that I proposed above (i.e. $Bp^{T}N^{T}X=t$) to recast this inequality into an LMI? 
Thank you.

Comment: No, $X$ as long as $p$ are optimization variables

Comment: Since the cost function $||Np||^2$ does not depend on X which is a variable matrix. Anyway, if confusing I add $X$.

Comment: It does not matter. The objective could be the zero function. The optimization variables need to be specified.

Comment: Ok, the post has been edited 10 minutes ago.

Comment: yes c>0. Thank you for the help

Comment: yes it comes from control theory.

Comment: You can use 5 tags. Better use them, within reason. It increases the audience and the chances of getting an answer from someone who has the knowledge to answer.

Comment: Have you taken a look at other questions with the [LMI tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-matrix-inequality)? Perhaps a similar question has been asked before.

Comment: Can you link such a question? Thank you